# Odoo 12: Many2one ondelete message?

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

Is it possible to change(edit) default ondelete message in Many2one field?

My field is:

```
parent_id = fields.Many2one("pgp.organizational.classifications", string="Parent classification", select=True, ondelete='restrict')
```

Default message is like this, but I won't to add my message:

```
"Odoo Server Error - Greška kod provjere

The operation cannot be completed, probably due to the following:
- deletion: you may be trying to delete a record while other records still reference it
- creation/update: a mandatory field is not correctly set

[objekt s referencom: pgp.organizational.classifications - pgp.organizational.classifications] "
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by overloading unlink method.
Here is the code if it helps someone:

```
> @api.multi
>     def unlink(self):
>         for field in self:
>             if field.parent_id:
>                 raise UserError(_('It is not possible to delete a record that is already used in transactions!'))
>         return super(YourClass, self).unlink()
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change it in the Many2one field's declaration.

Code which generates this message is there: https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/12.0/odoo/service/model.py#L120-L154

Seems to be tricky to overload

Answer (score 0):

Restricting and cascading deletes are the two most common options. RESTRICT prevents deletion of a referenced row. NO ACTION means that if any referencing rows still exist when the constraint is checked, an error is raised; this is the default behavior if you do not specify anything. (The essential difference between these two choices is that NO ACTION allows the check to be deferred until later in the transaction, whereas RESTRICT does not.) CASCADE specifies that when a referenced row is deleted, row(s) referencing it should be automatically deleted as well. There are two other options: SET NULL and SET DEFAULT. These cause the referencing columns to be set to nulls or default values, respectively, when the referenced row is deleted. Note that these do not excuse you from observing any constraints. For example, if an action specifies SET DEFAULT but the default value would not satisfy the foreign key, the operation will fail.